# Mesh faces disoriented when interpolating between two different vbo's

Tags: java, opengl-es, glsl, shader, interpolation

So, I'm using java with opengl es and have a mesh I am displaying using an obj (wavefront) parser. I have a single mesh that I exported from blender and so far I am able to display it to an android phone display. I am now trying to animate the mesh using keyframe animation, because skeletal animation is much harder to implement. I have two vbo's of the mesh in two different positions. I'm not sure if there is a de facto standard method for keyframe animation within shaders but I couldn't find it so I figured out a formula that would help me interpolate between these two vbo's at a given time. The formula is as follows

```
float ratio = ((passedTime/AnimationDuration))
```

in VertexShader:

```
GLPosition = ratio * (this is difference->)(endVBOVertex - StartVBOVertex)) + startVBOVertex.
```

So if AnimationDuration is 8 seconds and passedTime is 4 seconds ratio would equal .5 . The ratio is then multiplied to the Difference between the vertices in the start vbo and end vbo. This value is then added to The startVbo vertex so the correct position can be calculated per vertex. So If ratio = 0, 0 Is multiplied to the difference equalling 0, and then added to the original vbo vertex starting point. leaving us with the mesh pose that was started with. If ratio = 1, it is then multiplied by the difference and then added to the starting vbo vertex position giving us the end vbo with the mesh in the end position. The mesh looks fine when the ratio is 0 or 1. However, (heres the problem) in between 0 and 1 some faces of the mesh are rotated leaving holes in the mesh. At ratio = .50 is the worst which rotates some of the faces 45 degrees or so; leaving a rectangle face of the mesh with a diamond in it and 4 see through triangles. as I get closer to 0 or 1 these affected faces rotate back into a correct position making the whole mesh correct. Also the position of the mesh looks decent when interpolating between these two vbos; meaning overall the mesh can be seen in the proper pose but some faces are being rotated and affected in a weird way (when ratio is between 0-1) which is leaving me with a see through mesh.

{If you made it this far I greatly appreciate your time and apologize if I left anything unclear. I also Am saying thank you so much in advance for any and all advice.

I have depth Testing Enabled, I know i'm assigning all the uniforms and attributes right because I wouldn't be able to end up with the mesh In the correct pose at ratio = 0 || 1. The Vbo's have the same number of vertices.

This is my Vertex Shader:

```
uniform mat4 u_Matrix;//uniform for our matrix

attribute vec4 a_Position;//Original vertex position

attribute vec2 a_TextureCoordinates;

varying vec2 v_TextureCoordinates;

attribute vec4 b_Position;//Next vertex position to interpolate too

attribute vec2 b_TextureCoordinates;


uniform float ratio;

// (currentTime - StartTime)/animationDuration
//so If the animation lasts 8 seconds and 4 seconds have passed ratio
//will equal .5 and half the difference it takes for the first vbo to reach the second vbo will be added.

void main() {  
      v_TextureCoordinates = (a_TextureCoordinates + ((b_TextureCoordinates - a_TextureCoordinates) * ratio));
      gl_Position = u_Matrix * (a_Position + ((b_Position - a_Position) * ratio));
}
```

This is my Fragment Shader:

```
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D u_TextureUnit;


varying vec2 v_TextureCoordinates;


void main() {
      gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_TextureUnit,v_TextureCoordinates);
}
```

[Close Up of Head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwEvm.jpg)

[Ratio at 50%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVo9H.jpg)

Comment: *"the worst which rotates some of the faces 45 degrees or so"* can you explain this? Do you've a screen shot? You perform a linear interpolation. Each vertext is shifted along a straight line from on position to the other. With this approach rotations (like arm on an shoulder) can't be animated. Should the texture coordinates not be equal in both meshes? Note, the vertices in both meshes have to  have a corresponding order.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I Don't want to show screenshots because I would like to keep my design disclosed for now. Basically I have 5 spheres (head, Body, 2 hands, and 2 feet) set up in a humanoid way. Nothing is connecting them (the concept connecting them is supposed to be magnetic). I Have set up these spheres with an Ik Rig in blender and animated a walking sequence using keyframes. some of these spheres might be rotated by the ik rig, i was not aware that lerp did not support rotation. Should I be using sphereical lerp then? Is there a simple opengles function that can implement this such as mix()?

Comment: *"I Don't want to show screenshots because..."* so no one can help you here. I can guess only, but probably you need something like [Bone Morphing](https://wiki.synfig.org/Doc:Basic_Bone_Morphing).

Comment: @Rabbid76 You are 100% correct. I apologize for being un-necessarily difficult. I shouldn't expect any answers at all if I am unwilling to co-operate, sorry. I cant embed photos because I have too low a reputation with the site but it has provided me with links to the photos. One is a close up of the head and another of the whole mesh; both at ratio = 50%. As ratio gets closer to 0 or 1 these faces blend back to normal making a non transparent mesh. I appreciate your input so far and am currently investigating if this is due to vertex order. Note: This is one whole mesh in a single vbo.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Also originally I was not interpolating the texture coordinates but tried it to see if the weird affect would disappear, but nothing changed. I'm actually hoping to avoid skeletal animation because the implementation is more in depth and difficult than keyframe animation; and i've spent weeks trying to implement it to no avail so reluctantly I went for keyframe animation. I will also be looking into wether I can implement this with a different interpolation method that supports rotation. Again thank you for your input this far and anymore advice would be beyond greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically doing a standard lerp (linear interpolation) on the mesh data, which can be done using the mix() function.

```
v_TextureCoordinates = mix(a_Position, b_Position, ratio);
gl_Position = mix(a_TextureCoordinates, b_TextureCoordinates, ratio);
```

Everything looks fine to me in the shader. I'm a little concerned that you're interpolating the UV texture coordinates though??? It's a highly unusual approach for a character anim? Usually the texture coords do not change when animating.

One of the big problems with vertex blending is that you get some very strange deformation if the poses are significantly different. I'm guessing your artefacts are possibly due to this? (one of the reasons why animated hierarchy's  are usually preferable)

Comment: :D Thank-you for the function. I was unaware of the mix function (Still have a-lot to learn with Opengl-es). Originally I wasn't lerping between the texture coordinates and had (v_TextureCoordinates = a_TextureCoordinates;). However when I saw the faces were deformed I changed it hoping that was the problem, but It wasn't. What would be a significant difference in poses? Essentially I have a Humanoid character made of 5 spheres(body, head, limbs). The Two Poses being lerped are one foot out and the other pose with all limbs in middle so that i can lerp to another pose with the other foot out.